# Electrostatics of non-equilibrium situations

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, non-equilibrium

In footnote 1 of Chapter 13 of Ashcroft and Mermin, they remark that

> The only case we shall discuss in which the local equilibrium distribution is not the uniform equilibrium distribution (13.1) (with constant $T$ and $\mu$) is when the spatially varying temperature $T(\mathbf{r})$ is imposed by suitable application of sources and/or sinks of heat, as in a thermal conductivity measurement. In that case, since the electronic density $n$ is constrained (electrostatically) to be constant, the local chemical potential will also depend on position, so that $\mu(\mathbf{r}) = \mu_{equilib}(n, T(\mathbf{r}))$. In the most general case the local temperature and chemical potential may depend on time as well as position.

Note that (13.1) is simply the Fermi function with a local temperature and local chemical potential, in general.

My question is **why can we say that $n$ is electrostatically constrained to be constant**? In a measurement of thermal conductivity, we generally have an open circuit and in this case I suppose I can argue that there are therefore no macroscopic fields (and so $n$ must be constant, else there would be macroscopic fields). But if I am not at open circuit, why must this be the case? For example, if we are analyzing the Thomson effect, then I have both a temperature gradient and a current (not at open circuit). Is $n$ constant throughout my sample in this case too?

Answer (score 1):

A varying electronic density would imply an accumulation of charge, since we assume the background density of positive charge (ions) is constant. Moreover, let me show that we cannot have a static accumulation of charge, that is charge density $\rho \ne 0$ with no time dependency $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$.

From the continuity equation we have $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{j} = - \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0,$$
where $\mathbf{j}$ is the current density. Ohm's law state that
$$ \mathbf{j} = \sigma \mathbf{E},$$
where $\sigma$ is the the conductivity (which we assume to be uniform) and $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field. We take the divergence of both sides and get
$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{j} = \sigma \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}.$$
Now the left hand side vanishes, as we showed above, and the right hand side is proportional to $\rho$ by Gauss's law.

Note that we use Ohm's law in order to formulize the notion that charge is moved by electric field. This formulation also allows us to see when the statement is false, i.e. in which situations we can get $\rho \ne 0$:

1. For an insulator $\sigma = 0$ and indeed we can have charge distribution while electrostatic is still valid (strictly speaking the only case).
2. When $\sigma$ is not uniform we get an accumulation of charge given by $$ \rho = \frac{\mathbf{E}  \cdot \nabla \sigma}{\sigma}.$$

Comment: Superb. I think in your last line you mixed up “left” and “right” though, right? Also, can this be asserted without Ohm’s Law? We are here doing a derivation so as to conclude Ohm’s Law — I’m not sure we can assume it a priori.

Comment: You also have to assume that $\sigma$ is a constant *wrt* to  temperature and that can only be true approximately. To the extent it is constant it is an assumption and so is the uniformity of $n$ in general, I think; a reasonable assumption but an assumption nevertheless.

Comment: @EE18, regarding your first comment you are absolutely left. I fixed that and also explained why I used Ohm's law. In principle one can also use Lorentz force and argue that the resulting velocity have to obey some constraints but I think this would be messy.

Comment: @hyportnex, not sure how temperature dependence comes in. Unless of course you mean that the temperature itself depends on time or space. So even if $\sigma$ depends on temperature the explicit assumption that  $\sigma$ that is constant wrt both space and time imply that temperature is also constant.

Comment: this is exactly what I meant. $\nabla \cdot( \sigma \bf E) =\nabla\sigma \cdot \bf E + \sigma\nabla \cdot \bf E$ and $\nabla \sigma = \frac{d\sigma}{dT}\nabla T$ meanwhile the quote in the question explicitly assumes that $T=T(\bf r)$ but what if $T=\bf c \cdot \bf r$, so that $\nabla T = \bf c = const$, the case of thermoelectricity.

Comment: @hyportnex I’m not sure I totally follow your comment but do you agree that Ashcroft and Mermin are not assuming any sort of constitutive relationship in their footnote? It seems to be a model-agnostic assertion.

Comment: I cannot comment competently on A&M but, per your quote, they did assume that $T=T(\bf r)$. Then it is not obvious that $\nabla \cdot (\sigma \bf E) = \sigma \nabla \cdot \bf E$ unless $\sigma$ is independent of temperature.

Comment: @hyportnex is correct, the assumption that the temperature is spatially varying is right there in the quote. I kind of missed it when I wrote my answer. So indeed they seem to assume $\sigma$ is independent of temperature. I think my answer still stands as I explicitly assume $\sigma$ is uniform (and also discuss the non uniform case, regardless of what cause  $\sigma$ to vary spatially)

Answer (score 0):

Following Ashcroft and Mermin, let's use Gaussian units. Ampere's law is
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\nabla \times \vec{H} = \frac{4\pi}{c}\vec{J}_f + \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial\vec{D}}{\partial t}.
\end{equation}
If the electric field is static, the partial derivative of $\vec{D}$ vanishes. Therefore,
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\nabla\cdot\vec{J}_f = 0.
\end{equation}
Equation of continuity then tells us that $\rho_e = -en$ is constant. Here $\rho_e$ is the electronic charge density and $n$ is the number density. We do not need a constitutive relation like Ohm's law to come to this conclusion.

**About constancy of $n$, not just time independence**: A slightly more rigorous explanation for constancy of $n$ beyond the elementary reasoning in the comments is to look at the distribution function in presence of a dc electric field. It is given by equation (13.22) in the book and is
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
g(\vec{k}) = g^0(\vec{k}) - e\vec{E}\cdot\vec{v}(\vec{k})\tau(\mathcal{E}(\vec{k}))\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathcal{E}}\right).
\end{equation}
As you see, $g$ depends solely on $\vec{k}$ and not on $\vec{r}$. The number density is just the integral of $g$ over the $k$-space with an appropriate normalising factor.

Comment: I could be wrong, but as far as I can tell we have at the end only here established that $\rho(\mathbf{r},t) = \rho(\mathbf{r})$ (that is, that it's time independent). It's not clear to me that we've established that it's position-independent too. Why are we not allowed $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ changing in space, so that (given an assumed constant background density of positive ions), $n(\mathbf{r})$ also depends on space?

Comment: In metals, when there is a static electric field, all the free charges are driven to the surface. What remains behind is the bound charges whose density is independent of position in a homogeneous sample.

Comment: Hmm, I will have to think about this. I am not sure I can accept that A&M’s analysis is restricted to metals, but perhaps? At any rate, I think this latter argument is equivalent to yaron’s right? The standard proof of zero field and charge density in metals uses the infinite conductivity limit of Ohm’s Law?

Comment: Chapter 13 is about metals so we are on right track. A&M also invoke electrostatics so we are permitted to use elementary consequences of Coulomb's laws. Note that we do not require Ohm's law in electrostatics because there is no current. The only reason for using Ampere's law is to prove that $\rho$ is independent of time.

Comment: But I don’t think this is an elementary consequence. The result about zero electric field in a metal you quote holds if and only if $\sigma \to \infty$, which is not something even AM conclude for metals subsequently! I will have to continue to think about this, but I’m not sure I think this is what they have in mind here.

Comment: @EE18, I updated the post with some more information.

Comment: Thank you Amey. I am going to think about this a little more now. I have a sneaking feeling that this claim by AM is completely model-agnostic (whereas what we have here assumes spatial homogeneity, which may not be true if temperature varies with space), but perhaps I am wrong.